# EmberJS - display models in reverse order or by date order

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a simple Ember app that gets an array of models like so:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find("swap");                                                                                                                     
  }
});
```

I then output them in the view just like so:

```
{{#each model}}
    output stuff here
{{/each}}
```

This all works fine. I also have a form that lets people add new instances of this model, and it works fine and adds the new record to the bottom.

However, I'd like to do it in reverse. I have two options as far as I can see:

- output the array in reverse, and when a new one is added, add it to the top, not bottom
- each model has a `createdAt` property with a date, so order each model by the `createdAt` attribute in descending order

I think the second option makes more sense, but I'm not sure how to do about it.

Currently I only have an `App.IndexRoute` and then I have a `App.ApplicationController` which I've added some custom properties to. I presume I need to add another property or method to get the data from the store and order it by `createdAt`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jack, you need to use [sortAscending](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html#property_sortAscending) and [sortProperties](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html#property_sortProperties)

```
App.SomeController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    sortProperties: ['order'],
    sortAscending: true
});
```

**EDIT**
Note that if you're using a number for your ID column and you want to sort by that, then you'll need to explicitly convert it to a number:

```
/**
 * Explicitly forces the model ID to be viewed as an integer, allowing correct numeric     sorting
 */
order: function() {
    return parseInt(this.get('id'), 10);
}.property('id'),
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me on the right track! I had to swap my controller to `ArrayController` (instead of just `Controller`) and then update my view to `{{#each controller}}` instead of `{{#each model}}`.

Comment: there's just one more problem, when I add a new model to the array, it's added at the bottom, and not the top?

Comment: Fixed it! I wasn't setting a `createdAt` property when creating the model. Now I've done that, it's all working perfectly. Thanks.